# Auto sum in a mysql table when a data is entered in another mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables :- entry and result

The structure of entry is as follows :-

```
Name    Department  Units_Sold  Month
John    Sales           3   January
John    Sales           6   January
Ana     Retail          11  January
Rick    Marketing       1   February
Vicky   Sales           4   March
Ana     Retail          2   March
Vicky   Sales           9   March
Vicky   Sales           1   March
```

Each user enters the number of unit sold. Name, Department and Month are fetched from the server, when a user logs in and enters the "Units Sold".

When this entry is being made by the user I want another table to automatically update the monthly report. The 2nd table "result" is having the following structure :-

```
Name    Department  January February    March
John    Sales            9         0      0
Ana     Retail           11        0      2
Rick    Marketing        0         1      0
Vicky   Sales            0         0     14
```

In this table, the fields:- Name, Department, January, February,... December are static. I want to update the sum of "Units Sold" by each user for month when he/she makes an entry into the 1st table.

Can anyone, please suggest on this ?

Thanks !!

Comment: You might be better using a view? It resembles a tables, but it's just a SQL statement backing. Also - your schema - how do you account for different years?! Once you get to December - what happens?

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar, it is possible to do this only with a single table, the 1st one. I can add another field after month, "Year" which will be auto fetched from the server. I just want to print a table which shows, the monthly sum of units sold for each user when the year is given as an input. I am using PHP to print the SQL table.

Comment: You can create a view from 1(+n) tables.. all it is, is a SQL select statement, masquerading as a table, you can't update it, as it's dynamically reading from the backing statement.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is produce what's called a Pivot Table, using the data stored in your first table.  It's a relatively complex collection of aggregate functions that is well worth learning - especially if you have anything to do with financial reporting. [This site](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78) has a good intro into doing what you are asking.